# Authenticating From Another Site

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Hey guys I am trying to authenticate my solution from another website I have in mvc3 .net c#, the other site uses this post as authentication :

http://www.othersite.com/Account/logInToCMS?username=UNAME&password=PWD

I tried the following

```
<form  method="post" >
<input name='username' />
<input name='password' />
<div class="button"><%: Ajax.ActionLink("Login", "http://www.othersite.come/Account/logInToCMS" , new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })%></div>
</form>
```

but the response would result in an error which is:

"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:50505/account/http%3a/www.othersite.com/Account/logInToCMS"

So if i could somehow remove the "http://localhost:50505/account/" part it would work

Comment: if it is ANOTHER web app... just use a plain URL... don't use the helpers. You can always have that login URL in your web.config to change it anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ajax.ActionLink` is meant to be used by specifying the `Action` and `Controller` on the web application that your form exists in. If you look at the method overloads for `Ajax.ActionLink` you'll see you must specify at least the `Action`. Essentially what you are saying when you call ActionLink is that the `Action` you want to call is called `http://www.othersite.come/Account/logInToCMS`...which of course is incorrect.

If you are using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) then have a look at the [jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and `jsonp` for cross domain scripting.

Comment: Then what is the alternative?

Comment: @CharbelWakim looks like I updated with an option at the same time as your comment. If you are not already using jQuery I strongly recommend that you start. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Put a HTML submit button and give Url as 'action' attribute of HTML Form.

Comment: can you please elaborate the answer ?

Comment: @CharbelWakim think he is saying update your form tag by setting the action attribute like this `<form method="post" action="http://www.othersite.come/Account/logInToCMS">`...then use a submit button to submit the form.

Comment: @Craig if i do so i will get a white page with the response that is why i need to use ajax

Comment: @CharbelWakim came across your post and I was just tryig to clarify what Furqan was saying, of course this is not ajax though.